# Requirejs Optimizer not compiling

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, r.js, js-amd

I have been using requirejs and am having trouble getting the optimization tool to work. All I want to do is optimize my javascript files into one script file with all my dependencies included.

All my file are in the one js/ folder and I have a sub folder vendors/

I have a config file which looks like this(config.js):

```
requirejs.config({

baseUrl: ".",
out: "main-built.js",
deps: ["main"],

paths: {
jquery: "vendor/jquery", // v.1.10.2
bootstrap: "vendor/bootstrap",
ajaxform: "vendor/ajaxform",
skrollr: "vendor/skrollr",
jqueryform:"vendor/jqueryform"
},

shim: {
bootstrap: {
  deps: ["jquery"],
  exports: "bootstrap",
},

   ajaxform: {
  deps: ["jquery"],
  exports: "ajaxform",
},
        jqueryform: {
  deps: ["jquery"],
  exports: "jqueryform",
}

}
});
```

And I have an main javascript file (main.js) which looks like this:

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'function') {
define('jquery', function () { return jQuery; });
}


define(["jquery","bootstrap", "ajaxform","skrollr"], 
function($, bootstrap,  ajaxform, skrollr) {

//have other code here 

});
```

I also created a build file:

```
({
baseUrl: ".",
paths: {
jquery: "vendor/jquery", // v.1.10.2
bootstrap: "vendor/bootstrap",
ajaxform: "vendor/ajaxform",
skrollr: "vendor/skrollr",
jqueryform:"vendor/jqueryform"
},
shim: {
bootstrap: {
  deps: ["jquery"],
  exports: "bootstrap",
},

   ajaxform: {
  deps: ["jquery"],
  exports: "ajaxform",
},
        jqueryform: {
  deps: ["jquery"],
  exports: "jqueryform",
}

},
name: "main",
out: "main-built.js"
})
```

All the build file does is compress the main.js file itself and doesn't include all needed files.

I've been trying to get this working on and off for weeks and can't seem to get it right so any help would be REALLY appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a modules entry to your build file with your main module, as in:

```
modules: [
    { name: 'main' }
]
```

You can see all the options for the build file here: https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

Comment: Thanks for your replay Blatt,

That doesn't seem make any difference.

It's strange it outputting the comment of the skroller.js:
/*! skrollr 0.6.30 (2015-08-12) | Alexander Prinzhorn - https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr | Free to use under terms of MIT license */

but the code which below it seems to be the start of bootstrap:


I've checked out the link to example.build.js but I can't see anything that I'm missing there. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that your subfolder is 'vendors', but you're using 'vendor' to reference the folder in your build file?

Comment: No my folder name is vendor. I can seem to get it to compile jquery and bootstrap bu none of the other files and also the triggers I have in my main.js (i didn't include in code)